# "Intercept" enqueing of 3rd party's JS file

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, cache

I'm using a 3rd-party plugin, but I **need** to load the non-minified version of a specific JS file of the plugin, to avoid some image preloading caching; in the AJAX call when preloading some images, the minified JS uses param `cache:!0` that breaks a specific functionality that I need...

So, the relevant code in the plugin reads:

```
        wp_enqueue_script( 'woo-variation-gallery', esc_url( $this->assets_uri( "/js/frontend{$suffix}.js" ) ), array(
            'jquery',
            'wp-util',
            'woo-variation-gallery-slider',
            'imagesloaded',
            'wc-add-to-cart-variation'
        ), $this->version(), true );
```

where `$suffix` is calculated a little above (that's pretty standard in every plugin basically) like this:

```
        $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
```

So, temporarily I got around this by setting `SCRIPT_DEBUG` to `true` in my *wp-config.php*, but it doesn't feel right loading non-minified scripts site-wide just for a single script that needs to be loaded in its non-minified version...

So, is there any hook involved while enqueuing scripts, to hook into in my *functions.php* file in order to replace the script's `$src` from the plugin's `/js/frontend.min.js` to `/js/frontend.min.js` before loading it?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've made manual modifications to the file but don't know how to make the same modification to the minified versions to workaround what the plugin does? Would it not be easier to dequeue and deregister the script then re-register and re-enqueue it but with your own copy instead? Instead of trying to fix a hole in your cars tire while it's still driving at 60mph, why not stop it and replace the tire with a new one instead? This Q is an X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/), there are much easier ways to solve your problem than what you've asked about.

Comment: @TomJNowell no, I haven't made any direct changes to the non-minified version of the JS file... If that was the case, I'd use a JS minifier to minify its code... Indeed I've written my own code to extend its functionality in a way I needed (wrote some jQuery code utilizing an event handler of the plugin - `on('hide_variation.wvg', function() {`)...

Comment: and have you raised this with their support route?

Comment: Of course, but it being a *freemium* plugin, I assume they reply only to the paid customers, while ignoring their free ones...

Comment: you should still do it, keep in mind that 3rd party product support questions are off-topic here so this question is already on _thin_ ice. I haven't closed it because modifying an enqueued assets URL may be useful for other reasons

Comment: Is this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/396350/214235 the correct process to de-queue and de-register the `min.js`, and then re-enqueue the `.js` file instead? Also, I assume for re-enqueuing I'll use the same exact params as the author used, just change $src from `.min.js` to `.js`, right?

Comment: you'll want to keep the same handle but I suspect that answer to be correct. The order things run in will matter as you can't deregister something that hasn't been registered yet

Comment: @TomJNowell although the solution to de-register/de-queue/re-enqueue is totally off topic, would you care to help me sort it out? I actually tried it, and I get a JS error, although I did everything right!

Comment: And basically, I suspect there is no hook filter involved while registering a JS script, right?

Comment: Ahhhh, I had used a priority of 100, as the example I used had used, that's why I got the error... I changed it to 10, and indeed the correct, non-minified, script was loaded!

Comment: So @TomJNowell in order to reply to your previous answer where you "accused" me of falling into the X Y problem, that's 1000% not the case... You see, I'm a coder, not a "mouse" developer... I precisely know/can feel the correct way to deal with a situation involving programming. And that's exactly why I thought that I could prevent the "wrong" file from loading, instead of having it load, and then de-register it and register the "correct" one - the one that would suit my need... But anyway, that doesn't add anything to the topic, just had to let it out!

Comment: there's no accusation or malign intent, the x y problem is a common mistake and a fundamental part of how humans work, made by everybody regardless of seniority/role/industry/purpose. It's not something you grow out of, it's something everybody has to be actively mindful of that creeps into everything. Nobody said this makes you a mouse developer, or that only inexperienced people do it, everybody does it even me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deal with this by letting the minified JS load normally, and then de-registering and de-queuing it, and finally enqueuing the non-minified one... Although personally I'd consider this an indirect method, it's probably the only way to do it, since there is obviously no way to hook into the process of originally enqueuing a script...

So my solution was inspired by a comment to my question by @TomJNowell and by this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/396350/214235) to another question also!

So the code I used was this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wvg_load_non_minified_js', 10, 0);
function wvg_load_non_minified_js()
{
    wp_deregister_script('woo-variation-gallery');
    wp_dequeue_script('woo-variation-gallery');

    wp_enqueue_script('woo-variation-gallery', esc_url(plugins_url() . '/woo-variation-gallery/assets/js/frontend.js'), array(
        'jquery',
        'wp-util',
        'woo-variation-gallery-slider',
        'imagesloaded',
        'wc-add-to-cart-variation',
    ), WOO_VG_VERSION, true);
}
```